# Determine the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2.4.6...(2n)}{1.3.5...(2n-1)}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I determine the convergence/divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2.4.6...(2n)}{1.3.5...(2n-1)}}$?

I tried using the Ratio Test

$|a_n|=\frac{2.4.6...(2n)}{1.3.5...(2n-1)}$

$|a_{n+1}|=\frac{2.4.6...(2n).(2n+2)}{1.3.5...(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

$\lim_{n -> \infty}{|a_{n+1}|/|a_n|} = \lim_{n->\infty}{\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}}= 1$ therefore I can't reach any conclusion.

I don't know another way to solve this. Please help.

Comment: The convergence test one should *always check first* is whether the general term goes to 0 or not.

Answer (score 3):

Hint for every n we see that the even numbers are greater than corresponding odd numbers. Ie $2>1,2.4>3,2.4.6>1.3.5.. $ thus $\frac {2}{1}>1,\frac {8}{3},\frac {48}{15}.. $ thus each term is greater than $1$ thus sum of  product diverges